# Как к своей форме прицепить стиль формы битрикса?

Tags: форма, битрикс

Есть своя форма (можно сказать без стиля). Надо страничку в админке привести к единому стилю с битриксом. Как? Какие стили использовать? Возможно, стоит формировать форму не руками, а какими-то стандартными методами битрикса?

Answer (score 1):

Есть в битриксе такая штука, редактор форм называется. Можешь через нее создать свою форму.
Также есть компонент с аналогичным названием, делаешь тестовую страницу помещаешь на неё компонент, делаешь форму какую надо. по умолчанию применяются собственные стили битрикса.
Если нужно один в один с какой то формой то в файерфоксе дополнением (плагин) установи firebug, в ie просто f12, в хроме аналогично (либо правой кнопкой мыши-> проинспектировать элемент).

Answer (score 0):

Ты каким браузером пользуешься? Ели Опера, то там есть такая штука как "Проинспектировать элемент". Если FF, то там тоже есть подобная штука, как и в опере. Или просто смотри html код и разбирай.
Смотришь какой стиль, применяешь к форме и применяешь также ко своей форме этот же стиль.

Comment: В битриксе еще есть класс CForm, пока не могу заставить его работать.

Comment: @good, FF - > FireBug

Answer (score 0):

Не понятно, что такое своя форма. Если это в битриксе, то просто подцепить классы. А если ну другом сайте, то дернуть css как есть и тоже прописать нужные классы.